# Animation with more flexibility and better performance in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I need a marquee text animation (text moving from one side of screen to another), so I subclass the animation class (after googling some tutorial and copy&paste) and get it work. But the animation looks not smooth enough. While there may be some techniques I don't know about animation, I wonder if I should get aware of any advanced way of making animation (e.g. OpenGL) if I need precise control and better performance?

BTW:
1. this animation is core to my app, so I need it to be fully customized(moving speed control, ontouch event support, etc.)
2. I want to place the animation on an activity because I need some menus&popups which would be hard to draw without an activity I think(maybe I'm wrong as I'm a newbie of android dev).

Comment: plz check http://www.ivity.asia/2010/12/01/extended-marquee-in-android/   - it's work fine for me

Comment: @KPBird Thanks, what I try resembles the way you provide, but I suspect I need more control and better performance of the animation in the future so I ask for any way to achieve that even if the way is complicated.